# Covert an HTTP POST with headers and body request to Python (Telerik Fiddle)

Tags: python, api, post, request, fiddler

I am using the following in **Telerik Fiddler** in order to create a POST request and it is successful:

> POST https://login.random.com/connect/token HTTP/1.1 Connection:
>   Keep-Alive Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Accept:
>   application/json Authorization: Basic XyXyXyXyXyXyXyXyXyXyXy=
>   Content-Length: 105 Host: login.random.com
>
> grant_type=password&username=xxx&password=xxxx&scope=random.api.external

and now I am trying to convert that into a Python script but it fails (returns error 400):

```
import json
import requests
import http.client

headers = {
    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic XyXyXyXyXyXyXyXyXyXyXy=',
    'Content-Length': '105',
    'Host': 'login.random.com'
}

body = {
  'grant_type': 'password',
  'username': 'xxx',
  'password': 'xxxx',
  'scope': 'random.api.external'
}


response = requests.post('https://login.random.com/connect/token', headers=headers, data=body)
```

I have also tried including all the above in the headers and it failed (error 400).

Am I missing a library maybe? The details are correct in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. In Telerik Fiddler you can download a Code (Convert to Python) plugin and get an idea of how the final script should look like. After amending and testing, the final script is given below:

```
try:
    req = urllib.request.Request("https://login.random.com/connect/token")

    req.add_header("Connection", "Keep-Alive ")
    req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded ")
    req.add_header("Accept", "application/json ")
    req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic XyXyXyXyXyXyXyXyXyXyXy= ")

    body = b"grant_type=password&username=xxx&password=xxxx&scope=random.api.external"

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, body)

except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    if not hasattr(e, "code"):
        print('False')
    response = e
except:
    print('False')

print('True')
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was searching google for how to convert fiddler to python and found your comment. Why did you use urllib instead of urllib2? When I use the plugin to convert to python it uses urllib2. Like: `req = urllib2.Request("https://website.com")` where you have `req = urllib.request.Request("https://website.com")` ... is there a difference? Should I be doing it your way? *edit*: Nevermind. I'm using the same libary, imported like this `import urllib.request  as urllib2`.

Comment: @SCool Yes. urllib provides the urlencode method which is used for the generation of GET query strings. urllib2 doesn't have this function. That is why urllib is often used along with urllib2.